# Excess padding while importing an Xcode 12 project to Xcode 13 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode

I imported my SwiftUI project which was created on Xcode 12 to Xcode 13 beta 5. However, when the app loads there is a lot of excess padding on top of the NavigationView. Has anyone else faced this issue? Because there was nothing such when I created and deployed on Xcode 12. Also, when I relaunch the app manually on my iPhone, the padding goes away for a while, and then randomly appears after a while.

1. The screen with excess padding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOrIH.png
2. Screen without padding/expected output:
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFoiu.png

Here's the Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack {
                ForEach(data) { item in
                    Text(item.category)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("My Passwords")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like an extra `NavigationView` somewhere. Double check your code

Comment: Nope, not that I know of. If it was an extra NavigationView, then it should have popped up right when running on Xcode 12 itself. Also, this padding disappeared for a while when I relaunched the app, and then came back after 10-20 seconds.

Comment: It appears on its own or after you recreate the view that has it? It is a common mistake for people to think they are going back but they are actually just re creating. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: It just appears on its own, without even navigating to any view at the first place. Also, that's the first screen, on load up. Also, I did try refactoring my code using Xcode 13 beta 5, but it simply just wouldn't barge :(